# Minimal degree difference for $k$-critical graphs on $n$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

For a finite, simple, undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ let $\delta(G)$ and $\Delta(G)$ denote the minimum and maximum degree of $G$, respectively.

Is there a constant $K\in\mathbb{N}$ with the following property?

> Whenever $n,k$ are integers with $n\geq 4, k\geq 1$ and $n>k$, there is a [$k$-vertex critical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_graph) graph $G=(V,E)$ with $|V|=n$ and $\Delta(G)-\delta(G) \leq K$.

Comment: k-[vertex critical] ?

Comment: Right - forgot to insert link, will do.